# Why is 'steal' time gradually increasing?

Tags: debian, kvm, cpu

I'm tracking CPU usage on a VM on a lightly-loaded host. Everything appears to be functioning normally on all the VMs, but collectd is reporting a gradually increasing 'steal' time:

[image]

The actual steal time reported is always either 100% or 0%, but as time passes, the 100% spikes get closer and closer together.

Both VM and host are running vanilla Debian 8. We didn't notice the same effect when both were running Debian 7 on a different physical host.

Is this a quirk of collectd or is KVM really slowly taking CPU resources away from the VM?

Comment: I remember we have a in-house software that didn't free memory... Then we forced to use `valgrind` profiler. Do you have any in-house program?

Comment: However if you don't have any in-house program , You can try-testing via some memory analyzer.

Comment: Memory usage is roughly constant at about 170Mb/512Mb the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

CPU steal time is (according to `man proc`):

> Stolen time, which is the time spent in **other operating systems** when running in a virtualized environment.

If you have more than one VM on that host; or if you keep adding VM's on that host; or if you're overcommitting resources (especially CPU) you can run into this issue. [I made a post about how overcommitting resources is bad in a virtual environment that may also be of help](https://serverfault.com/questions/686655/is-a-vm-with-2-cpus-really-faster-than-one-with-4-cpus/686852#686852).

Comment: "If you have more than one VM on that host; or if you keep adding VM's on that host; or if you're overcommitting resources (especially CPU) you can run into this issue." — which if these will cause a linearly increasing 'steal' time lik in the graph?

Comment: Memory use [is constant](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203653/why-is-steal-time-gradually-increasing/241865?noredirect=1#comment357338_203653) and CPU is fairly low the whole time (except for the 'steal' time which is obviously an artifact).

Comment: It's a KVM host running vanilla Debian 8 (as mentioned in the question). At the time there were no other VMs running and it made no difference as other guests were added, the steal time behaved exactly the same.